# Pass Variable From Jquery to ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the code below:

```
$('#bayar').click(function(){    

    var totalHarga=0;

    $('.totalHarga').each(function () {
       totalHarga+=parseFloat($(this).text().trim());
    });

var kodeTrx=$('#kodeTransaksi').val().trim();
var diskon=$('#diskonPembelian').val().trim();
var grandTotal=totalHarga-diskon;
var diskonPersen=grandTotal/totalHarga;
var jumlahBayar=$('#jumlahBayar').val().trim();
var pelanggan = $('#pelanggan').val().trim();
var sisaBayar=jumlahBayar-grandTotal;

$.ajax({

  type : "post",
  url : "input_nota_penjualan.php",
  data : {
        kodeTransaksi: kodeTrx, totalTransaksi:totalHarga,      
        diskonTransaksi:diskon, GrandTotalTransaksi:grandTotal, 
        bayarTransaksi:jumlahBayar, pelanggan:pelanggan,  
        sisaTransaksi:sisaBayar
      },
  success: function (response) {            
    alert('Suksessss');        
  },
  });

};
```

the jquery variable is not readable by ajax, or the value in the ajax function is empty.
How to get variables from jquery to read in ajax function block?

Comment: please provide your HTML code @Pri Yanto

Comment: are you sure this `$('#kodeTransaksi').val` has a value in your html?

Answer (score 0):

You wrongly close the function,please check last line of the below code,

```
$('#bayar').click(function(){    

var totalHarga=0;

$('.totalHarga').each(function () {
   totalHarga+=parseFloat($(this).text().trim());
});

  var kodeTrx=$('#kodeTransaksi').val().trim();
  var diskon=$('#diskonPembelian').val().trim();
var grandTotal=totalHarga-diskon;
var diskonPersen=grandTotal/totalHarga;
var jumlahBayar=$('#jumlahBayar').val().trim();
var pelanggan = $('#pelanggan').val().trim();
var sisaBayar=jumlahBayar-grandTotal;

$.ajax({

  type : "post",
  url : "input_nota_penjualan.php",
  data : {
        kodeTransaksi: kodeTrx, totalTransaksi:totalHarga,      
        diskonTransaksi:diskon, GrandTotalTransaksi:grandTotal, 
        bayarTransaksi:jumlahBayar, pelanggan:pelanggan,  
        sisaTransaksi:sisaBayar
      },
  success: function (response) {            
    alert('Suksessss');        
  },
  });

});
```

Comment: thanks @Suriya Subramaniyan,  I was fix it, but the result is the same

Comment: not an error, but the data block {...} in the ajax function is of no value, I want the data to be taken from the variable already declared above, eg var codeTrx, var discount and so on